# python mutagen clarification on editing metadata

Tags: python, mutagen

I wanted to edit the meta data of a mp3 file.So as suggested by many i used mutagen.
[Image of properties of the mp3 file before running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hcVy.jpg)

The output of pprint of the mp3 file before running the program

```
MPEG 1 layer 3, 273092 bps (VBR, LAME 3.99.1+), 44100 Hz, 2 chn, 278.87 seconds (audio/mp3)
album=Achcham Yenbadhu Madamaiyada
albumartist=A.R.Rahman
artist=Aditya Rao, Aaryan Dinesh Kanagaratnam, Sri Rascol
author=Thamarai, Madhan Karky, Vignesh Shivan, ADK, Sri Raskol & Pavendhar Bharathidasan
composer=A.R.Rahman
date=2016
discnumber=01/01
encodedby=music
genre=Tamil
lyricist=Thamarai, Madhan Karky, Vignesh Shivan, ADK, Sri Raskol & Pavendhar Bharathidasan
title=Showkali
tracknumber=01
version=music
```

I wanted to change the genre so I did this:

```
import mutagen
path = 'C:/wamp/www/music/songs/Showkali.mp3'
m=mutagen.File(path,easy=True)
m['genre']='melody'
m.save()
print(m.pprint())
```

[The properties of the mp3 file after running the above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmBvm.jpg)

The output of pprint of the mp3 file after running the program

```
MPEG 1 layer 3, 273092 bps (VBR, LAME 3.99.1+), 44100 Hz, 2 chn, 278.87 seconds (audio/mp3)
album=Achcham Yenbadhu Madamaiyada
albumartist=A.R.Rahman
artist=Aditya Rao, Aaryan Dinesh Kanagaratnam, Sri Rascol
author=Thamarai, Madhan Karky, Vignesh Shivan, ADK, Sri Raskol & Pavendhar Bharathidasan
composer=A.R.Rahman
date=2016
discnumber=01/01
encodedby=music
genre=melody
lyricist=Thamarai, Madhan Karky, Vignesh Shivan, ADK, Sri Raskol & Pavendhar Bharathidasan
title=Showkali
tracknumber=01
version=music
```

The affected output can be seen by using pprint() but most of the metadata in the properties tab of the mp3 cannot be seen as you can see in the picture.
Why does this occur?.Could anyone point out the mistake?...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [after using python mutagen,metatags not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972762/after-using-python-mutagen-metatags-not-displayed)